# Nested Controllers in Angularjs/Bootstrap Image Carousel Issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am new to Angular development. I have a list of images which is being retrieved from a remote server and needs to be displayed in two different image carousels. At the moment, I have a setup like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
   <div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl"></div>
   <div ng-controller="CarouselCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

Where the data is retrieved and stored in the scope of MainCtrl, then used in both image carousels. But that ends up with the two carousels linked together, so that any operations on one are reflected on the other.

Plunker example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/e79x0d2fF5zwx0UwXIxW?p=preview

What is the best and right way to fix this, so that the same underlying data set can be used by both carousels, but their interactions are not tied together?

Edited: I forgot that about the loose way that parameters can be set/defined. Both carousels were using the same parameter (.active) to determine their active slide. So when one changed .active, the other reflected the change. Changing them to .activeA and .activeB de-linked in in the way I needed them delinked.

Comment: May I recommend UI Bootstrap? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: I am using UI Bootstrap to do this. (See the Plunker, it's a modification of the demo code demonstrating my problem.)

Comment: I see that now, thx. Have you explored the $carousel directive and how it works? If it works via $emit/$on or listening for $scope variable changes, it's likely that you may have to modify it to use local processes.

Comment: I haven't created a full answer yet, but this has what you're looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/ig2CVMbDi1lrTDLj0j8C?p=preview

Comment: Ah, so you put both the carousels under the same CarouselController. I can see why that would work. Unfortunately, I may have oversimplified my example. In my full application, one of the carousels is on a gmap infowindow, and the other is on a slide-out side tab.  So, it's more like mainCtrl->sideTabCtrl->carouselCtrl for one, and mainCtrl->mapCtrl->carouselCtrl for the second.

Comment: No, I see: you changed the active paramter to two different paramters. Duh. If they are both depending on the same active parameter, they are going to switch to that active tile. I just changed that in my Plunker and it is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that both Carousels are being bound to the same $scope.kittens property, this is two way data binding, changing the index of one, will change the other, the solution is Either to create a Directive with an Isolated scope that will create a carousel that has it is own separate scope, Or if you want to keep it simple, construct another Scope property (kittens2) that is a copy of the first property :

```
$scope.kittens2 = angular.copy($scope.kittens);
```

this will create a new scope property that is not data bound with the first one, then, in your second carousel change the ng repeat to iterate to the new scope property that has its own scope now.

```
 <slide ng-repeat="kitten in kittens2" active="kitten.active">
```

this way you are separating the scopes, this solution is just to keep the example simple, but the right way is to use directives with Isolated scopes.

Note that doing :

```
$scope.kittens2 = $scope.kittens
```

will not work because you are binding the kittens2 property again with the kittens property, angular.copy copies the old object to a new object with a different reference.